# Question about "./devel/setup.bash" while sourcing setup.bash

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Normally i source my environment with "source /devel/setup.bash" but i noticed in the tutorial that there is a period before the file location "source ./devel/setup.bash" Why is that period there?

p.s. This is my first post so im not sure where to really ask this question.

---

Edit:

This is the tutorial I was following: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/ExaminingPublisherSubscriber

> ```
> # In your catkin workspace
> ```

```
$ cd ~/catkin_ws
$ source ./devel/SETUP.BASH
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340879/question-about-%22./devel/setup.bash%22-while-sourcing-setup.bash/) by [humpback](https://answers.ros.org/users/50615/humpback/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-01-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-02**:
Could you please link to "the tutorial" you refer to in your question text?

Perhaps even include a quote of the section you mention has the dot in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Normally i source my environment with "source /devel/setup.bash" but i noticed in the tutorial that there is a period before the file location "source ./devel/setup.bash" Why is that period there?

A `.` (dot) in a path refers to the "current directory".

It makes whatever path comes after the dot relative to the current directory.

So `source ./devel/setup.bash` `source`s the file `setup.bash` in a directory called `devel` that *must* be in the current directory.

However, all paths *not* starting with a `/` are relative to the current working directory, so the dot is not actually necessary here.

> This is my first post so im not sure where to really ask this question.

In the end this is not really a ROS question (more a general Linux one), but given the context it's fine.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-02**:
If you want to know more about this, you could Google for something like `linux current directory dot`).

**Comment by [humpback](https://answers.ros.org/users/50615/humpback/) on 2020-01-02**:
Wow, thank you for the quick response. Very well written.